# Which angle causes an object to land quickest?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Say a canon is where the circle is, and it shoots two different canonballs at different angles, but at the same speed, which angle would make the cannonball hit the ground first?

[image]

Intuitively I'd think they'd hit at the same time, however, I remember a formula describing the second coordinate $y$: $y = - 1/2 \cdot g \cdot t^2 + v_{0y} \cdot t$

Where $t$ is the time, and $v_{0y}$ is the starting velocity. Thus a high $v_{0y}$, would lead to a greater total time $t$, thus it would hit A first. This seems to be missing something though.

Comment: perpendicular components of the object's velocity are independent, so the one which has the smallest initial velocity perpendicular to the ground will hit the floor first.

Comment: @Hayeder: And another way to put it is height. The one that rises the least will hit the ground first.

Comment: It will hit the ground quickest if you point it to -90°.  I.e. straight down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fixed muzzle velocity the time the cannonball stays in the air depends on the vertical component of the velocity, so trajectory A would stay in the air longest. The trajectory with the longest duration is firing directly upwards.

If the angle to the ground is $\theta$, then the vertical velocity is $v_0sin\theta$, and the time in the air (neglecting air resistance) is $2v_0sin\theta/g$, where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Answer (score 2):

Set the equation $y = -0.5gt^2 + V_{y_0} t$ equal to zero. You get two solutions one at time $t = 0$, and the second one is when the object hits the ground again at $t = 2V_{y_0}/g$. Of course, $V_{y_0} = V_0 \sin(\theta)$. Thus you have: $t (\text{travel}) = 2 V_0 \sin(\theta)/g$. The closer the angle to 90 degree the longer the flight time.

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring here the resistance of air, right? I am not going to give you the solution which you can find in any physics text book, but rather tell you how to derive it yourself.

Try expressing initial speed $v_0$ as a function of your angle $\alpha$ (hint: sines and cosines), then solve for $t$ in your formula. From there the solution should be fairly obvious, but you can always verify by finding the angle $\alpha$ which corresponds to smallest $t$.

Answer (score 0):

$v_{0y}$ would be greater for cannon A in your picture, so A would go higher and stay in the air longer.